# Applications of multinomial theorem

Tags: combinatorics

Can someone explain to me thoroughly the applications of **Multinomial Theorem** in the problems of *permutation and combination*? I don't really understand when to use it and when not. How should I identify after seeing a problem if it demands the use of *multinomial theorem*? Someone please help me out in this(I'm a 12th grader).

Comment: Two words: Mississippi formula. Give that a Google.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you want to distribute or assign $n$ (distinct) things into $k$ distinguishable parts of specified (known) sizes $n_1,n_2,\cdots.n_k$ you use the multinomial coefficient,

$$ \binom{n}{n_1,\cdots,n_k}. $$

Note the binomial coefficient is a special case with $n_1=j$ and $n_2=n-j$ if you're picking $j$ items.

Often you'll have to get *creative* in re-interpreting a counting problem; this is an unavoidable curse (and blessing, if you like math and want there to be more of it!) in combinatorics.

So for instance, to multiply out $(x_1+\cdots+x_k)^n$ and find the coefficient of $x_1^{n_1}\cdots x_k^{n_k}$, imagine you wrote out the multinomial $n$ times as $(x_1+\cdots+x_k)\cdots(x_1+\cdots+x_k)$. There are $n$ factors, and when distributing you must pick one term from each factor. Thus, your $n$ "things" are the factors, and the "distinguishable parts" are the variables $x_i$ for $i=1,\cdots,k$.

Or, let's say you want to find how many strings can be formed from rearranging the letters $AAABBC$ (preserving multiplicity). There are $n=6$ positions, and each position must be assigned a letter $A,B,C$; there must be $3$ assigned to $A$, $2$ assigned to $B$ and $1$ assigned to $C$, so the count is $\binom{6}{3,2,1}$.

Comment: I understand what you're saying...but in a situation where we have n groups(containing a certain no. of objects) and we have to select a total no. of r objects from the n groups such that we might not select a single object from a group, then why do we look for the coefficient of x^r in a certain expansion (I don't understand where it comes from) in order to get our answer? Can you please explain that bit?

Comment: @AbhinavTahlani What does that question have to do with multinomial coefficients? That seems like a separate question that you should post separately. Also it doesn't seem to me like you've given enough context in your comment for me to answer it anyway.